# google analatycs track dynamic pages

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, google-analytics

I decided to choose Google Analatycs to track the pages.

I have custom/dynamic pages in php and i want to track all the pages.

on my project every users can create a page and the URL looks like

www.mysite.com/user_page_name

so i want to track all the details of the page `user_page_name`

how can i retrieve the details of this page in php ?

currently i just created a profile in google analatycs center with my domain.

I am using PHP-CODEIGNITER.

Thank you.

**UPDATE : YES,IT IS POSIBLE ,BUT NOW I NEED TO GET THE DETAILS OF A GROUP OF PAGES.
ASSUME THAT A USER ON MY SITE CREATED 5 PAGES ,SO I NEED THE DATA OF EACH PAGES.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're wondering how to retrieve analytics data using php and display it on you website (such as how many unique visits the page X had between the dates of d1 and d2), Google offers an analytics API for PHP:

http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

I've actually used the Java version, it works quite well (at least for basic data retrieval, I haven't tried anything too complicated)

Comment: i tried something like this...but i need the details of a particular page,

Comment: Look at the docs: http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/wiki/GAPIDocumentation. As I said I'm not familiar with the PHP APIs but with the Java ones you can get per page results (such as how much visitors a certain page had). At any rate, if you want to get this data from Goole Analitycs you need to use one of their APis

Comment: yea..i got it....but now with updated question...i need to get a group of pages data..one nob way is sending some different requests and collect the data which is not good..

Comment: Well, I don't wanna talk about things I don't know completly (in this case the PHP APIs for Analitycs), so I'll just add another comment instead of updating my anwer: the APIs allow you to make compelx queries when querying for a resource, such as all pages that have an URL starting with XXX or containing YYY.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer,actually my question is answered and i am not expecting a technical answer,ok,i think that i can use regular expression in filter,let me check,thanks for the answer ,cheers!!